# How to set multiple styles to an element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

tried creating a custom div named `container` and I cannot get the styles to work, in fact the lines 33-39 are prohibiting line 41 from working. I tried everything to get the `container` div to show up but no luck. Please help, thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en"><head>
</head> 
<style>
body
{       
    background-repeat:repeat;
    background-color: white;    
}
#container
{       
    position: relative; 
    margin: 0 auto;     
}
#p_1
{
    font-style:italic;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-color: black;
}
#p_2
{
    font-style:italic;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-color: black;
}
</style>
<script language = "JavaScript">
function initialize_container(container)
{   
    document.getElementById("p_1").innerHTML = "<p> output p1  </p>";

    var CONTAINER_TAG = document.getElementById("container");   
    CONTAINER_TAG.setAttribute("style", "width: 100px;");   
    CONTAINER_TAG.setAttribute("style", "heigth: 100px;");      
    CONTAINER_TAG.setAttribute("style", "border: 2px solid;");  
    CONTAINER_TAG.setAttribute("style", "border-radius: 25px;");    
    CONTAINER_TAG.setAttribute("style", "border-style: solid;");    
    CONTAINER_TAG.setAttribute("style", "border-color: purple;");   

    document.getElementById("p_2").innerHTML = "<p>  output p2 </p>";
} 
</script>
<body onload = "initialize_container('container')">
    <div id = "container">                      
        <p id = "p_1"></p>  
        <p id = "p_2"></p>  
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are overriding the `style` attribute each time you call `setAttribute`. They aren't additive.

Comment: So I have to put everything inside `setAttribute` once.., ok.

Comment: Yeah, that's why it is a `set` operation =]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just overriding the style attribute each time you call `setAttribute`. It is not additive. Make just one call `setAttribute` with all the style together

Try replacing this:

```
CONTAINER_TAG.setAttribute("style", "width:" + 100 + "px;");    
    CONTAINER_TAG.setAttribute("style", "heigth:" + 100 + "px;");       
    CONTAINER_TAG.setAttribute("style", "border: 2px solid;");  
    CONTAINER_TAG.setAttribute("style", "border-radius: 25px;");    
    CONTAINER_TAG.setAttribute("style", "border-style: solid;");    
    CONTAINER_TAG.setAttribute("style", "border-color: purple;");
```

with this:

```
CONTAINER_TAG.setAttribute("style", "width:100px;heigth:100px;border: 2px solid;border-radius:25px;border-style: solid;border-color: purple;");
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9BDxN/)

Also just asking for this:

```
document.getElementById("p_1").innerHTML = "<p> output p1  </p>";
```

Are you sure you want to put a `p` elemenent inside `p_1` element. Maybe you want

```
document.getElementById("p_1").innerHTML = "output p1";
```

Comment: You're right, I had no idea the `setAttribute` wasn't additive.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting attribute again and again, change the style of that element.

```
CONTAINER_TAG.style.width = "100px";   
CONTAINER_TAG.style.heigth = "100px";      
CONTAINER_TAG.style.border = "2px solid purple";
CONTAINER_TAG.style.borderRadius = "25px";
```

**TIP:**

One thing I noticed is as you are passing the id of the div as parameter in the function, so

```
var CONTAINER_TAG = document.getElementById("container");
```

should be `var CONTAINER_TAG = document.getElementById(container);`

Hope, this helps...

Comment: But the topic of the thread was to create a custom div using the DOM.

Comment: but that div id `container` is already there in DOM if you see and the way code written doesn't seem like he/she wants to create the element, instead it's about updating that particular element.

Answer (score 0):

By this process also you can give the syle for particular element.

```
CONTAINER_TAG.style.width = "500px";
CONTAINER_TAG.style.height = "100px";
CONTAINER_TAG.style.border =  "4px solid green";
```